# Трехмерный массив. как сформировать еще один вложенный массив?

Tags: javascript

как сформировать еще один вложенный массив? Вывод должен быть таким :

```
[
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ],
]
```

Код :

```
let arr = [];
for (let i =0; i < 3; i++){
arr[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
arr[i][j] = [];  
  for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    arr[j].push(k+1); 
   }
  }
} console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Правильно думаете что не верно, вам ещё нужно примерить переменную `i`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 благодарю! Вы как всегда -  . Сработало когда добавила - arr[i][j] = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем пустой массив. Во вложенном цикле создаем и наполняем новые массивы, которые пушим в первый:

```
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    const arrChild = [];

    for (let k = 0; k < 5; k += 1) arrChild.push(k + 1);
    
    arr.push(arrChild);
}
    

console.log(arr);
```

Оптимизируем:

```
const arr = [];
const arrChild = [];

for (let k = 0; k < 5; k += 1) arrChild.push(k + 1);
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) arr.push(arrChild);

console.log(arr);
```

Еще одна вложенность - похожим образом:

```
const arr = [];
const arrChild = [];
const arrDesc = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) arrDesc.push(i + 1);
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) arrChild.push(arrDesc);
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) arr.push(arrChild);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Это двухмерный массив. А нужно создать трехмерный..

Comment: Дополнил. Можете похожим образом дописать еще с десяток вложенностей :)

Comment: Чем вам так не нравится оператор `++`?)

Comment: Это сишный, в js рекомендуется родной применять ) Иногда и сахара бывает много )